# is UserController required?

Tags: php, cakephp

Before we start, I'm newbie in CakePHP

I'm creating a little system with 2 kinds of user:

- admin: has access to a CMS
- normal: has access to a control panel, with some configurations.

cake PHP is giving me an error:

> Error: UsersController could not be found.

My `UserController` should be `AdminUserController` or `NormalUserController`.

What is going wrong?

Comment: which version of cakephp ?

Comment: You should configure controller in auth setting. Auth is used user controller default for authenticate users.

Comment: ManoharKhadka using 3. 
PrakashSaini i understood, but i need to change between tables. I have two login forms in the same page, for admin and normal users.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have one UsersController with multiple prefixes. One prefix is / which is your regular public site. The other is /admin which is your CMS.

Here is a CMS you can use or see how they have done it: https://icingcms.org

Here is the how to prefix routes:
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html

Here is how you check what the user have access to what prefix:
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#using-controllerauthorize